# How to use imagemagick compare so that the order does not matter?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using the `compare` command from imagemagick in my scripts to find out whether two images are identical or not. I recently found out that the order of the arguments to `compare` matters. Here are two images, one with transparent pixels and one without:

[image: no transparency]
[image: with transparency]

When I run `compare -metric AE img1.png img2.png null:` on these two files I will either get `1318` with an exit status of 1 or `0` with an exit status of 0. Is there a way to make the convert tool behave in a way such that the order I pass images to it does not matter? Or do I have to run `convert` twice and only let two images be equal if they compare as equal if both orders succeed? That sounds very wasteful as I'm doing a lot of comparisons including of much larger images.

This behaviour is not documented, is it? Is it intentional?

Comment: It likely has to do with one image having transparency and the other not.  Try adding -alpha off and you will get 0 for both. Or add -alpha set and you will get 1318 for both.

Comment: @fmw42 that is doing exactly what i want, thank you! If you copypaste your comment into an answer I can upvote it and mark it as the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely has to do with one image having transparency and the other not in Imagemagick compare.

Try adding -alpha off (so you do not include the alpha channel in one and not the other) and you will get 0 for both.

Or add -alpha set (so you include the alpha channel in both, but one image will be opaque alpha) and you will get 1318 for both.